# How to read entire row from database to c#?

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

Let's say the following code returns the entire result row:

```
using (SqlCommand cmdMessages = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Email where Sender = @usernameLog", conn))
{
    cmdMessages.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@usernameLog", Sender));

    using (SqlDataReader reader = cmdMessages.ExecuteReader())
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            Console.Write(); // Receiver's Name which comes from database
            Console.Write();// The message which comes from same row as the receiver's name
        }
    }
}
```

The query works fine in SQL Server.

Output from SQL Server:

```
 User      hi
```

I want to have the same output in console.

Comment: What makes you think that code doesnt return the whole row?  It may return several or many rows, in fact.

Comment: What happened when you used the indexer? `reader["some column name"]`

Comment: [Read](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-data-using-a-datareader) and be amazed.

Comment: My mistake! There was an exception about parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to display the values you are retreiving as you are iterating through the datareader, you can simply do this:

```
using (SqlCommand cmdMessages = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM Email where Sender = @usernameLog", conn))
{
     cmdMessages.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@usernameLog", Sender));
     using (SqlDataReader reader = cmdMessages.ExecuteReader())
     {
         int count = reader.FieldCount;
         while (reader.Read())
         {
             for(int i = 0 ; i < count ; i++) 
             {
                  Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(i));
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Use `int count = reader.FieldCount;` to count the number of fields you are returning. Then you are going to iterate through with a for statement.

If you only have 2 values you want to be displayed, you can simply replace the for with:
`Console.WriteLine(reader.GetValue(0) + " " + reader.GetValue(1));`

Answer (score 1):

to get column values you need:

```
while (reader.Read())
        {
               reader.GetString(1);
               reader.Getstring(2);
         }

or
reader.GetString("ColumnName1");
reader.GetString("ColumnName2");
```